# How to remove union all?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to remove union all for following query.

```
DECLARE @TEMP TABLE (ID INT,DESCR VARCHAR(20))
            INSERT INTO @TEMP
            SELECT 1,'A'
            UNION 
            SELECT 2,'B'
            UNION 
            SELECT 3,'C'
            UNION 
            SELECT 4,'D'

            SELECT DESCR,ID FROM @TEMP
            WHERE DESCR NOT IN ('A','B')
            UNION ALL
            SELECT 'A+B',SUM(ID) FROM @TEMP
            WHERE DESCR IN ('A','B')
```

Does any one suggest to use instead of union all

Comment: why do you want to do this, what are you actually hoping to achieve? it's not clear from you question what you want to do and why. Please add your desired output.

Comment: To add up IDs is a funny idea by the way.

Comment: Hi @ThorstenKettner id is just a name, if you have a any problem with id, you may use value instead of id.

Comment: Well, usually ID is an ID ;-) Okay, then. To get rid of `UNION ALL` here would lead to a rather clumsy query, but it would be possible. In order to write a correct query: Can `DESCR` be null in the table?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `group by` with `case`:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN DESCR IN ('A', 'B') THEN 'AB'
             ELSE DESCR
        END) as DESCR, SUM(ID) as ID FROM @TEMP
FROM @TEMP
GROUP BY (CASE WHEN DESCR IN ('A', 'B') THEN 'AB'
               ELSE DESCR
          END);
```

This does make two important assumptions:

- `DESCR` is unique, at least for the rows that do not contain `'A'` and `'B'`.
- The value `'AB'` is not in the data.

You can still do what you want if these are true, but the query might be a bit more complicated (and the table might require a unique id).

Answer (score 1):

When it is guaranteed that `DESCR` cannot be null in the table, then there is no `NOT IN` issue, and we wouln't need any extra null handling to mimic that.

What you would do is build pseudo groups. A "group" for every single non-A/B record and a real group for all A/B records:

```
select 
  max(case when descr in ('A','B') then 'A+B' else descr end) as descr, 
  sum(id) as id
from @temp
group by 
  case when descr in ('A','B') then 'A' else descr end,
  case when descr in ('A','B') then 0 else id end;
```

This pseudo grouping only works however when there are no duplicates in the table (e.g. two records for E/5). If there were, then we would have to generate a unique key on the fly.

EDIT: For completeness sake: If there can be duplicates in the table, we need a unique identifier. A simple solution is to use the undocumented `%%physloc%%`. (An alternative would be to select from a derived table where we create row numbers with `ROW_NUMBER`.)

```
group by 
  case when descr in ('A','B') then 'A' else descr end,
  case when descr in ('A','B') then 0 else id end,
  case when descr in ('A','B') then 0 else %%physloc%% end;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DESCR, CASE WHEN DESCR = 'A+B' THEN SUM(ID) ELSE MAX(ID) END AS ID
FROM (
        SELECT CASE WHEN DESCR IN('A', 'B') THEN 'A+B' ELSE DESCR END AS DESCR, ID
        FROM @TEMP
) a
GROUP BY DESCR;
```

http://rextester.com/FUTXBQ64727